Plot using Maple, the solid that is inside a hemisphere and outside a cylinder
Here is the full question : 
Plot the solid that is inside the hemisphere $z=\sqrt{25-x^2-y^2}$, outside the cylinder $x^2+y^2=4$ and above the $xy-$plane.
This is the solution that I came up with: 
c := cylinder([0, 0, 0], 2, 5, capped = false), view = 0 .. sqrt(21); 
g := hemisphere([0, 0, 0], -5, capped = true), scaling = constrained, view = 0 .. sqrt(21);
display(g, c);
and the resulting graph:
top view
bottom view
My problem is, how to empty the region where the cylinder and the hemisphere intersect at the bottom? (highlighted in red)
I know my solution is quite crude so any guidance to a better solution is much appreciated.

This solid will have three parts to its boundary:

The cylinder $x^2 + y^2 = 4$ where $\sqrt{25 - x^2 - y^2} = \sqrt{21} \ge z \ge 0$.
The hemisphere $z = \sqrt{25 - x^2 - y^2}$ where $x^2 + y^2 > 4$ and thus $0 \le z < \sqrt{21}$.
The $xy$ plane $z=0$ for $4 < x^2 + y^2 < 25$.

So try something like this:
with(plottools): with(plots): 
c := cylinder([0, 0, 0], 2, sqrt(21), capped = false, colour=cyan, style=patchnogrid): 
h := hemisphere([0,0,0], -5, capped=false,colour=green, style=patchnogrid):
p := plot3d([r*cos(theta), r*sin(theta),0], r=2..5, theta=0..2*Pi,
      colour=yellow,style=patchnogrid):
display(c,h,p,view=[DEFAULT,DEFAULT,0..sqrt(21)],
      scaling=constrained,viewpoint=circleleft):


